# Check whether the cron is running or not

Tags: logging, cron

I have a cron job with the following command.

```
30 1 * * * find /opt/check/logs/app*  -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 | xargs tar -czvPf /archive/backup_$(date +%F).tar.gz
```

This will find a particular log files and doing the backup.

When we run the above command manually, it will work. My issue is I am not able to ensure that this cron is running or not. Is there any way to add logs while the script is running ? (except crontab logs)

Comment: A quick hack would be to insert a `tee` command between the `find` and `xargs` in the pipeline and see if anything is getting written to the file.

Comment: You have to escape the `%` sign or it will be interpreted as a newline character with the rest of the line as standard input.